# How do you style the errored input fields with the jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin, and I want to add a class to the input fields that doesn't validate, i.e. add a red border.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### jQuery Validation

The validation plugin adds the class 'error' to the input with the validation error.

Therefore you can style it independently.

For example:

```
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: This adds the border around the error message, and not the input field.

Answer (score 1):

This form has the effect you want and uses the same plug-in, perhaps you could peek under the covers to see how they did it:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/marketo/

**EDIT**: I started peeking for you, but then Jon posted the answer.